# Java 8 List of List

Tags: java, kotlin, java-8, java-stream

I have one question regarding Java8 stream api. I have one class as below

```
class MyDetails(
    val fname:String,
    val lname:String,
    val myAccountList:List<Myaccount>
)

class Myaccount(
    val accID:String,
    val accType:String,
    val associateList:List<Associate>
)

class Associate(
    val associateID:String,
    val role:String
)
```

Now I want to get

> List of Myaccount

whose role is "**owner**"(Let us suppose).

For that i wrote below code but its not working

```
myDetailsObject?.myAccountList?.stream()?.filter { account ->
            account?.associateList?.stream()?.allMatch{associate ->
                println("Value of Role ${associate.role}")
                "owner".equals(associate.role)}!!
        }?.collect(Collectors.toList())?.toList()
```

Output for Print statement is-

```
Value of Role owner
Value of Role view
Value of Role read
Value of Role owner
Value of Role write
Value of Role write
Value of Role view
```

If **owner** is available in list why i am getting list of size zero?
But above code is not working for me..Any suggestion would be appreciated. Even though code syntax is in Kotlin but Java code would also be helpful.

Comment: If you need help with Java code, please do remove the kotlin tag (you can keep the kotlin syntax code)

Comment: when you say "not working" does it mean it doesn't compile? What compile error do you see? Or does it mean that you're not able to get the expected result, in which case what do you see as an actual result as compared to the expected result?

Comment: Yes..Not able to get expected result...i have written test cases this method.

Comment: Question updated...Plz chk

Comment: @FrankNeblung...First thing- can't paste same code in SO which i have written ...second thing- Kotlin doesn't have semicolon...Third thing- "String or string" I believe that all SO user have basic understanding of what person want to ask. It will be better to encourage positively other people rather than  "Downvote" ..If you have solution most welcome.

Comment: @FrankNeblung I admit it's better to have compiling code. But if this really prevents you from understanding the question (which to be honest shouldn't in this case), and you don't want to take some time to edit, then you can simply write a nice comment asking for clarification. Your comment sounds a bit harsh :/

Answer (score 3):

Why not simply use kotlin for the job?

```
fun wanted(candidates: List<Myaccount>) =
    candidates.filter { it.associateList.any { it.role == "wanted" } }
```

Answer (score 1):

By asking for 'allMatch', you expect all the elements to have 'owner'. use `anyMatch()` instead?

```
myDetailsObject?.myAccountList?.stream()?.filter { account ->
            account?.associateList?.stream()?.anyMatch{associate ->
                println("Value of Role ${associate.role}")
                "owner".equals(associate.role)}!!
        }?.collect(Collectors.toList())?.toList()
```

Answer (score 0):

The Java code to filter the accounts objects whose *all* the associates are owner and collect as list is

```
myAccountList.stream()
    .filter(account -> account.associateList.stream()
               .allMatch(associate -> "owner".equals(associate.role))
     .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

**EDIT:** (based on OP update)

If you want to pick an account if at least one of the associates' role is owner, then you have to use *anyMatch* in place of *allMatch*

Comment: Thanks for your response...account -> account.stream()..Is stream() will work here??

Comment: @jhon That was a typo to add a stream after account. Fixed it.

Comment: If you want to pick an account if **at least** one of the associates' role is owner, then you have to use *anyMatch* in place of *allMatch*